# Space and motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, drag, relative-motion

When we throw a ball upwards sitting in a running bus or train it directly comes to our hands but when we do the same sitting on a moving motorcycle the ball falls backwards. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in a train the air particles inside are moving with you, but on a bike your velocity relative to the air particles is different so the ball gets pushed by the air.
If there was no wind resistance and you threw the ball straight up while on a bike then it should share your velocity in the direction you are riding your bike.